# Filter multiple values with multiple attributes js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter, attributes

I want to filter the multiple attributes with multiple values

'arr' is a list of all products and f_... is the attribute like color or type.

'namet' is the chosen attribute from the user.

'keyt' is the values of each attribute like red, yellow and green.

```
 let arr = [
        { "id": 523, "f_105": ["992","996"],  "f_104": ["985"], "f_106":["1000"] },
        { "id": 524, "f_105": ["993","996"],  "f_104": ["984"], "f_106":["1001"] }
    ]
```

these arrays which user chose for searching

I can get the attrubites like this

```
var namet = ['f_106', 'f_106', 'f_105', 'f_105', 'f_104' ];
var keyt  = ['1000' , '1001', '993', '996', '985'];
```

OR

```
var chooenKey = ['f_106', 'f_105', 'f_104']
var chosenAttr = {
    "f_106": ["1000", "1001"],
    "f_105": ["993", "996"],
    "f_104": ["985"],
}
```

OR

```
var chosenAttr =
[
    {"f_106": ["1000", "1001"]},
    {"f_105": ["993", "996"]},
    {"f_104": ["985"]}
]
```

I want a method to loop to get result like variable 'filtered'

```
var filtered = d => 
        (d.f_106.indexOf("1000") > -1 || d.f_106.indexOf("1001") > -1) && 
        (d.f_105.indexOf("993")  > -1  || d.f_105.indexOf("996") > -1)  &&
        (d.f_104.indexOf("985")  > -1)
```

then put it here

```
const f = arr.filter(filtered);
```

You can also give another type to filter the product with multiple attributes.

Comment: What's the specific issue? Recall that you can access `d.f_106` either that way, or `d["f_106"]`.

Comment: I want a method or loop to generate a code like in variable filtered. If I have {"f_106": ["1000", "1001"]} in chosenAttr so the varible will be like var filtered = d => (d.f_106.indexOf("1000") > -1 || d.f_106.indexOf("1001") > -1)

Comment: So you'd want to iterate `chosenAttr` (each item called `attr` in this comment), and for each `attr` use the object key to see which property of `d` you're checking, and see if any of `d[attrKey]` values exist in `attrValue`, which could be done a variety of ways. You. might be over-thinking this :)

Comment: yeah maybe so how I can filter the product like in arr list.

Comment: By doing the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you examine the example I sent, I believe it will solve your problem.

```js
let arr = [
    { "id": 523, "f_105": ["992", "996"], "f_104": ["985"], "f_106": ["1000"] },
    { "id": 524, "f_105": ["993", "996"], "f_104": ["984"], "f_106": ["1001"] }
]


var chosenAttr =
    [
        { "f_106": ["1000", "1001"] },
        { "f_105": ["992"] },
        { "f_104": ["985"] }
    ]



function filterArr() {
    var arrCopy = arr;

    for (i = 0; i < chosenAttr.length; i++) {
        for (var key in chosenAttr[i]) {
            arrCopy = arrCopy.filter(function (item) {
                var is_match = false;

                for (var idx in chosenAttr[i][key]) {
                    let val = chosenAttr[i][key][idx];

                    if (item[key].indexOf(val) > -1) {
                        is_match = true;
                    }
                }
                return is_match;
            });
        }
    }

    return arrCopy;
}

var filterData = filterArr();
$('#response').html(JSON.stringify(filterData));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre>
<code id="response">
  
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: I'm so glad I could help :)